# question on isomorphism of abelian von neumann alegbras

Tags: analysis, reference-request, von-neumann-algebras

I came across the following sentence which I do not know how to prove when reading a paper,

"Suppose $(X_0,\mu_0)$ is a non-trivial atomic probability space, then we can identify $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T},\lambda)$ wih ${\overline{\otimes}_{n\geq 0}}L^{\infty}(X_n,\mu_n)$, where $(X_n,\mu_n)=(X_0,\mu_0), \forall n\geq 0$."

Toward this, I guess we need to understand (in the context of von neumann algebras):

1, Show that ${\overline{\otimes}_{n\geq 0}}L^{\infty}(X_n,\mu_n)=L^{\infty}(\prod_{n\geq 0}X_n, \prod_{n\geq 0}\mu_n)$ (the RHS should not be $L^{\infty}(\oplus_{n\geq 0}X_n, ?))$, since $\oplus X_n$ may be countable)

2, Understand when we would have $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)\cong L^{\infty}(Y,\nu)$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, what do you mean by $\bigoplus X_n$?

As far as two goes, the category of abelian von Neumann algebras is dual to the category of standard measure spaces. So $L^\infty(X)\simeq L^\infty(Y)\Leftrightarrow X\simeq Y$ as measure spaces. As far as the last part all diffuse standard measure spaces are isomorphic. So inparticular $\mathbb{T}$ is isomorphic to $\Pi X_n$ for any $X_n$.

Comment: thanks, you are right, $\oplus X_n$ does not make sense, I was thinking $X_n$ as modules when writing this, because I am often not sure whether to choose $\oplus M_n$ or $\prod M_n$ when generalizing some isomorphism that holds for finite tensor. BTW, could you give some references for the fact mentioned in your answer, I believed this is true but have trouble to find a proof.

Comment: I don't have it in front of me right now, but I'm pretty sure this should be in Takesaki "Theory of Operator Algebras I"

Comment: Ok, thanks, I would check that, BTW, the paper mentioned in the question is the one by Popa and Sasyk on computation of first cohomology of Bernoulli action.